# Schedulers.computation() is executed on MainThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, networkonmainthread

How can I perform this code in the background thread?

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())

onNext()
{
     touchEverythingInTheUiThreadFromBackgroundThread();
}
```

Comment: Could you share more code? What is the source of events? Don't you confuse `subscribeOn` with `observeOn`?

Comment: Put question first, removed rubbish

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure your `.doOnNext()` is executed on the specified scheduler, then change your `.subscribeOn()` to `.observeOn()`. Intuitively `.observeOn()` determines what scheduler is used for everything that comes after that.

`.subscribeOn()` only affects what scheduler is used to run `onSubscribe()` method of your observable creation. What happens later heavily depends on what exactly you are subscribing to or as @akarnokd puts it: what is the source of your events. It's not safe to assume that items are going to be emitted on scheduler specified in `.subscribeOn()`. Actually there are at least a few examples where that assumptions doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> Thread.currentThread().getName())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(name -> Timber.d("Worker thread: %s, Handle thread: %s", name, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```